# how to make interaction with GridGestureContainner(Canvas) in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

What I have Tried is?

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Canvas x:Name="UiComponent">
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LowOpacityBackground" Color="White" Opacity="0.01"/>
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <Canvas x:Name="GridContainnerGesture" Background="{StaticResource LowOpacityBackground}" Width="1500" Height="800" Canvas.ZIndex="0" PointerPressed="GridContainnerGesture_PointerPressed" PointerWheelChanged="GridContainnerGesture_PointerWheelChanged">

        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="ImageContainner"  Width="1500" Height="800" Canvas.ZIndex="1" PointerPressed="ImageContainner_PointerPressed" PointerWheelChanged="ImageContainner_PointerWheelChanged">

        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>

</Canvas>
```

My C# code:

```
 private void GridContainnerGesture_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GridContainnerGesture_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ImageContainner_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ImageContainner_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CanvasControl CanvasControl1 = new CanvasControl();
        CanvasControl1.Width = 1500;
        CanvasControl1.Height = 800;
        ImageContainner.Children.Add(CanvasControl1);
        CanvasControl CanvasControl2 = new CanvasControl();
        CanvasControl2.Width = 1500;
        CanvasControl2.Height = 800;
        GridContainnerGesture.Children.Add(CanvasControl2);
    }
```

My layout must be like this only.When i click on screen ,i want to fire GridContainnerGesture(Zindex=0) pointerPressed event instead of ImageContainner(Zindex=1) PointerPressed event.How to do this?I don't want to change Zindex!!

Comment: When I tested your code snippet and clicked on the screen, it always triggered the GridContainnerGesture_PointerPressed event. Did you only trigger the ImageContainner_PointerPressed event? Can you show more details about your unexpected behavior? In addition, Why do you use the ImageContainner canvas to overlay the GridContainnerGesture canvas and subscribe PointerPressed event for ImageContainner?

Comment: While Zindex of ImageContainner canvas is 1,it will trigger only the ImageContinner PointerPressed event.How will get GridContainnerGesture_PointerPressed event?
I am going to draw Some images at different locations on CanvasControl1 .Whenever I click on drawed  image I want to trigger ImageContainner PointerPressed Event and  some places of CanvasControl1 are empty(Images, not Placed Area) ,if I click on that area I want trigger GridContainnerGesture_PointerPressed event?I have updated Code also!

Comment: By testing, we didn't find any method can trigger the GridContainnerGesture_PointerPressed event when click on the empty area. The CanvasControl1 completely overlays the GridContainnerGesture canvas, it only responds to the ImageContainner's PointerPressed Event.

Comment: thank you.i am also think like that only.But hope to check is there is any way.thanks!!